# Varying focal length camera import problem

Tags: camera, import

I'm trying to import a camera from Nuke to Blender, which has a varying focal length. The camera animation is imported correctly, but the focal length is static - set to the first frame value.

I tried Alembic and FBX, both give the same result. If I reimport to Nuke - the focal length is animated as it should be.

Any ideas how I can import it correctly. Or at least how could I copy the animation values to Blender ?

Thanks,
Lukas

Comment: Focal length sounds way to specific to import/export. Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. What does camera parameters have to do with material export?

Comment: Like materials, camera parameters are application specific properties that can't be easily ported between different software, nor do exchange formats have data structures to store them, as far as I know.

Comment: No, camera parameters are not software specific, and they are stored in FBX and Alembic files. Unfortunately it's not possible to import the focal length animation into Blender.